# EFcore log queries of database

Tags: .net, database, logging, ef-core-3.1

I'm used to develop in .net framework. For a fast login of EF queries I just use Database.Log

```
public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext {

public DatabaseContext()
        {
            Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

I search the equivalent in core?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core: Log queries for a single db context instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680174/entity-framework-core-log-queries-for-a-single-db-context-instance)

Comment: The duplicate shows the two available options - either use `optionsBuilder.LogTo` to quickly write eg to the console, or use the .NET Core's logging middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a custom LoggerFactory for DI

**LoggerFacotry**

```
internal class EFCoreLoggerFactory : LoggerFactory
{
    public EFCoreLoggerFactory() : base()
    {
        base.AddProvider(new EFCoreLoggerProvider());
    }
}
```

**ILoggerProvider**

```
internal class EFCoreLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) => new EFCoreLogger(categoryName);
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

**ILogger**

internal class EFCoreLogger : ILogger
{
private readonly string _categoryName;

```
    public EFCoreLogger(string categoryName) => this._categoryName = categoryName;

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, System.Exception exception, Func<TState, System.Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (_categoryName == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name && logLevel == LogLevel.Information)
        {
            var logContent = formatter(state, exception);
            //**Change the log way you want**
            Console.WriteLine(logContent); 
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(logContent);
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => true;
    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => null;
}
```

**Enable LoggerFactory in your DBContext:**

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true); //Enable paramters in log
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(new EFCoreLoggerFactory());
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: nothing personal, just an awesome facepalm moment -_-